# How to split('@') script with Javascript inside a razor view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = null;
}
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<div id="login-page">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="form-login">
            <h2 class="form-login-heading">sign in now</h2>
            <div class="login-wrap">
                <input type="text" id="txtUsername" class="form-control" 
placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
                <br />
                <input type="password" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Password">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="login.html#myModal"> 
Forgot Password?</a>

                    </span>
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" id="btnLogin"><i 
class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>
                <hr>


                <div class="registration">
                    Don't have an account yet?<br />
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        Create an account
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        <div id="divError" class="alert alert-danger collapse">
            <a id="linkClose" href="#">&times;</a>
            <div id="divErrorText">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#btnLogin').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/token',
                    method: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: {
                        username: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                        password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                        grant_type: "password"
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        localStorage.setItem('accessTokenP', 
response.access_token);
                        //example@yahoo.com

                        var x = response.userName.toString().split('@'); 
                        localStorage.setItem('NameP', x[0]);

                        $('#divErrorText').text(JSON.stringify(response));
                        $('#divError').show('fade');
                        var url = "/Home/index";
                       window.location.href = url;
                    },
                    error(response) {
                        alert("error")
                        $('#divErrorText').text(JSON.stringify(response));
                        $('#divError').show('fade');

                    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Source Error:

Line 128:                    success: function (response) {
Line 129:                        localStorage.setItem('accessTokenP', response.access_token);
Line 130:                        var x = response.userName.toString().split('@');
Line 131:                        localStorage.setItem('NameP', x[0]);
Line 132:

Source File: /Views/Home/Login.cshtml    Line: 130

Comment: whats wrong with it

Comment: The code you are showing is javascript not razor and the line of code should be valid javascript except for the asterixs you have added. So I'm unclear what your question is.

Comment: In MVC, @ is the respective char that allows you to use razor inside HTML

Comment: @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}

Comment: How to split email

Comment: //example@yahoo.com
                        var x = response.userName.toString().split('@'); at @symbol it throws an error

Comment: Learn 'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example' first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My bad, you were right to call out the fact that this javascript is in a razor file and that the error relates to Razor.  The example just didn't make that obvious.  I have edited the question to put that info back in the title and tag.  I finally understand the issue you are asking about.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @ is a reserved char in Razor, to get an actual @ char in your string you need to escape the @ char by doubling it up. so

```
   var x = response.userName.toString().split('@');
```

becomes

```
 var x = response.userName.toString().split('@@');
```

By escaping it this way, Razor understands that you are using the @ not as a Razor symbol but as a literal and a single @ will be placed in the string which is what you need in this case.